# How can I join these tables so I get only distinct values return regardless of whether there are nulls in the other tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My current query results in duplicate records being returned despite specifying distinct, if I remove my third join the query works fine; but I'd like those columns from the third table. This is definitely do to me being confused about the different types of joins so if someone could explain it to me that would be awesome. Oracle SQL btw

```
select distinct t.objectid as transformer_id,
CASE
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '006'THEN '006 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps >= 75 kVA'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '018'THEN '018 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps >= 75 kVA'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '084'THEN  '084 - PM LBT Loop F Dry Type - Brookdale Village'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '107'THEN '107 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '108'THEN '108 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '197'THEN '197 - SUB NW HD LBT LOOP TC [26]'
END AS group_number,
t.feederid as circuit_num, t.gps_x as lon, t.gps_y as lat, 
s.customerhousenumber as house_numb, s.customerstreetname as street_name,
s.crossstreet as cross_street, s.customertown as town, s.customerzip as zip
FROM ((mvtransformer t
INNER JOIN mvtransformerunit u
  ON t.objectid = u.transformerobjectid)
FULL OUTER JOIN vservicepoint_meterinfo s
  ON t.objectid = s.transformerobjectid)
WHERE (u.groupnumber = '006' OR u.groupnumber = '018' OR u.groupnumber = '084' OR u.groupnumber = '107' OR u.groupnumber = '108' OR u.groupnumber = '197');
```

edit:

Current output: All the specified fields, repeated for transformers that have multiple service point records (the s) associated with them; the relationship between them is one to many.

Desired output: Unique transformers only, return only the first associated record from service points.

Now that I think about it and after reading the comments, it really is kind of a flawed query. Problem is that my organization has no ER model for the database so I'm figuring out how everything is connected and what is storing what as I go.

I think if they need the addresses I'm just going to reverse geocode, but still I'm curious on what I'd have to do for the above to work.

Comment: What is the current and desired output of the query?

Comment: check edits @PavelBrziák

Comment: And how would you specify 'first' in the set of service points? Based on some rule?

Answer (score 0):

As Pavel Brziák mentioned in the comments, you need to define "return only the first associated record from service points" by mentioning the condition that makes a record “first”. 
Also you should consider the relationship between mvtransformer and mvtransformerunit  that might be one to many (if it is one to one you can remove the DISTINCT).  Despite having an ER you can execute the following query and give you a clue about the relationship of the tables (although in case the following query won’t return you any rows, you can never be sure that one day it might return one)

```
SELECT t.objectid
FROM mvtransformer t, mvtransformerunit u
WHERE t.objectid = u.transformerobjectid
GROUP BY t.objectid
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

Assuming that the aforementioned (mvtransformer and mvtransformerunit) association is one to one, you can use the following solution that takes the first (randomly) record from vservicepoint_meterinfo .

```
SELECT transformer_id,
   group_number,
   circuit_num,
   lon,
   lat,
   house_numb,
   street_name,
   cross_street,
   town,
   zip FROM (
select distinct t.objectid as transformer_id,
CASE
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '006'THEN '006 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps >= 75 kVA'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '018'THEN '018 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps >= 75 kVA'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '084'THEN  '084 - PM LBT Loop F Dry Type - Brookdale Village'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '107'THEN '107 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '108'THEN '108 - Conventional Stepdown, Taps'
    WHEN u.groupnumber = '197'THEN '197 - SUB NW HD LBT LOOP TC [26]'
END AS group_number,
t.feederid as circuit_num, t.gps_x as lon, t.gps_y as lat, 
s.customerhousenumber as house_numb, s.customerstreetname as street_name,
s.crossstreet as cross_street, s.customertown as town, s.customerzip as zip,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.objectid ORDER BY s.rowid) AS drank
FROM ((mvtransformer t
INNER JOIN mvtransformerunit u
  ON t.objectid = u.transformerobjectid)
FULL OUTER JOIN vservicepoint_meterinfo s
  ON t.objectid = s.transformerobjectid)
WHERE (u.groupnumber = '006' OR u.groupnumber = '018' OR u.groupnumber = '084' OR u.groupnumber = '107' OR u.groupnumber = '108' OR u.groupnumber = '197')
WHERE drank = 1;
```

In case you want to retrieve the record from vservicepoint_meterinfo  that

- Is being created first (and you have this information in column CREATED of table vservicepoint_meterinfo) replace s.rowid with s.created ASC
- Is being created last (and you have this information in column CREATED of table vservicepoint_meterinfo)  replace s.rowid with s.created DESC

Please take under consideration that this practice is not suitable for including this query in database VIEW that can be filtered (i.e. SELECT * FROM transformer_servpoints_view WHERE transformer_id = 123) since Oracle will have to pre-calculate the inner query by making a full table scan on mvtransformer